# Failed to create GitHub Repository Can't create repository: Name of Project 301 Moved Permanently in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, git

I was trying to push my codes to GitHub then I encounter this:

> Failed to create GitHub Repository Can't create repository: FCSITOfiiceLocator 301 Moved Permanently

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to GitHub and check if the project has not been renamed, renaming the project could cause a 301 since the URL to the project will change.

List your Existing Remote URL to verify if it has changed

```
git remote -v
```

Change Remote Url

```
git remote set-url origin {Your updated remote URL}
```

Comment: The Project is not showing on Github that's the problem once I import into version control -> Share Project on Github, a dialogue box appear I should add a comment then push, once am done it shows me that error.

Comment: To make your life easy just go to www.github.com sign in and create the repository first, in the Android Studio Terminal do a git remote add origin [Projetc Url], git add -A, git commit -m "your commit message, then do a git push -u origin master